# golang: Вставка данных в один массив из нескольких горутин

Tags: golang

Как правильно написать код максимально быстрой работы всех пяти функций `f1-f5` по вставке данных в один массив `test`? На примере кода, который работает криво:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var data = []string{}
var test = []string{}
var ch_i = []chan string{}
var ch_o = []string{}

var ch = make(chan string, 'z')

func f0() {
    for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
        data = append(data, strconv.Itoa(j))
    }
    fmt.Println("\n    data: ", data)
}

func main() {
    f0()
    // - - - - - -
    go f1("A", ch)
    go f2("B", ch)
    f3("C", ch)
    go f4("D", ch)
    go f5("E", ch)
    // - - - - - -
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("\nlen ch_i: ", len(ch_i), "\ncap ch_i: ", cap(ch_i), "\n    ch_i: ", ch_i, "\n ")
    fmt.Println("\nlen ch_o: ", len(ch_o), "\ncap ch_o: ", cap(ch_o), "\n    ch_o: ", strings.Join(ch_o, ", "), "\n ")
    fmt.Println("\nlen test: ", len(test), "\ncap test: ", cap(test), "\n    test: ", strings.Join(test, ", "), "\n ")
}

func f1(s string, ch chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)
        ch_i = append(ch_i, ch)
        test = append(test, s+data[i])
        ch_o = append(ch_o, "a")
        ch <- "a"
    }
}

func f2(s string, ch chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)
        ch_i = append(ch_i, ch)
        test = append(test, s+data[i])
        ch_o = append(ch_o, "b")
        ch <- "b"
    }
}

func f3(s string, ch chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)
        ch_i = append(ch_i, ch)
        test = append(test, s+data[i])
        ch_o = append(ch_o, "c")
        ch <- "c"
    }
}

func f4(s string, ch chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)
        ch_i = append(ch_i, ch)
        test = append(test, s+data[i])
        ch_o = append(ch_o, "d")
        ch <- "d"
    }
}

func f5(s string, ch chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)
        ch_i = append(ch_i, ch)
        test = append(test, s+data[i])
        ch_o = append(ch_o, "e")
        ch <- "e"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал синхронный массив, атомарность добавления в который гарантируется мьютексами:

```
type SyncArray[T any] struct {
    array []T
    lock  sync.Mutex
}

func (ca *SyncArray[T]) Append(val ...T) *SyncArray[T] {
    ca.lock.Lock()
    defer ca.lock.Unlock()
    ca.array = append(ca.array, val...)

    return ca
}

func (ca *SyncArray[T]) Array() []T {
    ca.lock.Lock()
    defer ca.lock.Unlock()
    return ca.array[:]
}
func (ca *SyncArray[T]) Len() int {
    return len(ca.array)
}
```

Работает довольно быстро. Бенчмарк для сравнения записи в массив из пяти горутин с последовательными добавлениями такого же количества элементов.

```
import (
    "sync"
    "testing"

    "example.org/concarray"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

const (
    numOfAppends = 100_000
    numOfWorkers = 5
)

func syncWriter(sa *concarray.SyncArray[int], val int, count int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        sa.Append(val)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func BenchmarkSyncArray(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sa := concarray.SyncArray[int]{}
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        for j := 0; j < numOfWorkers; j++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go syncWriter(&sa, j, numOfAppends, &wg)
        }
        wg.Wait()
        assert.Equal(b, numOfWorkers*numOfAppends, sa.Len())
    }
}

func BenchmarkPlainArrayt(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        arr := []int{}
        for j := 0; j < numOfWorkers; j++ {
            for k := 0; k < numOfAppends; k++ {
                arr = append(arr, j)
            }
        }
        assert.Equal(b, numOfWorkers*numOfAppends, len(arr))
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org/concarray
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
BenchmarkSyncArray-8              19      60360342 ns/op    21083928 B/op         44 allocs/op
BenchmarkPlainArrayt-8            51      24338208 ns/op    21083450 B/op         36 allocs/op
PASS
```

Видно, что синхронный массив проигрывает примерно в два с половиной раза по времени и делает больше аллокаций, но зато не портится при параллельном обновлении.

Я сделал вариант с каналами, когда есть выделенная горутина, модифицирующая массив, но этот вариант оказался гораздо медленнее

```
type MutiWriteArray[T any] struct {
    array    []T
    done     chan struct{}
    stream   chan T
    closed   bool
    finished sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewMultiWriteArray[T any]() *MutiWriteArray[T] {
    arr := &MutiWriteArray[T]{
        array:  []T{},
        done:   make(chan struct{}),
        stream: make(chan T),

        closed: false,
    }
    arr.finished.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-arr.stream:
                arr.array = append(arr.array, v)
            case <-arr.done:
                close(arr.stream)
                arr.closed = true
                arr.finished.Done()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return arr
}

func (mwa *MutiWriteArray[T]) Append(val ...T) *MutiWriteArray[T] {
    for _, v := range val {
        mwa.stream <- v
    }

    return mwa
}

func (mwa *MutiWriteArray[T]) Array() []T {
    return mwa.array[:]
}
func (mwa *MutiWriteArray[T]) Len() int {
    return len(mwa.array)
}

func (mwa *MutiWriteArray[T]) Close() {
    close(mwa.done)
    mwa.finished.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, буду изучать и разбираться.